# C# - WinScp- Envío de archivos por FTP

Tags: c#

tengo una consulta si se puede ocultar la extensión de un archivo .zip cuando se envía a un servidor por FTP.

Tengo un .bat que comprime archivos, luego mediante un algoritmo en c# (uso el complemento de WinSCP) envío dichos archivos .zip al servidor por FTP, pero me están pidiendo que no se muestre la extensión. Adjunto foto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Saludos Cordiales.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: cambiales la extension ...

Comment: Deberían inventar un curso en la Universidad de "Requerimientos sin sentido" .Una extensión de un archivo solo es relevante en Windows (¿¿y en linux??) para ligar el archivo con el programa que lo ejecuta, es decir para que cuando hagas doble click en él se abra el programa que lee el archivo. Windows en el explorador de archivo tiene la opción de ocultarlos, pero es solo una opción visual del explorador, y recalco que es una característica del explorador no es del archivo. Un archivo con una extensión cambiada o sin extensión puede seguir siendo abierto por su programa sin problemas

Comment: ¿Dónde en el servidor, en un visualizador del programa de c#??

Comment: Depende del propio WinSCP mostrar o no la extensión, eso es algo que no puedes controlar. Lo mismo pasa con cualquier otro programa o sistema operativo. Si quieres quitar la extensión como tal antes de enviar el archivo al servidor FTP, eso es otra cosa.